# Add library from nodemodule on keystonejs

Tags: keystonejs

I would like to know what is the solution to link a library that is in the node module to the default template.

[image]

Comment: Hi, You dont import package from node module. Node module is a place where all the installed packages are stored.

Thats package is already installed in your project, hence you just need to import it.
Maybe something like import MathJax from 'MathJax';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do that:

1. Create a script to copy required files from node_modules/mathjax folder to `public/js` folder and use `/js/mathjax/mathjax.js` in script tag
2. Create the route specifically for the lib in node_module 
   `app.use('/js/mathjax', express.static(path.dirname(require.resolve('mathjax'));`